# Electric Flux - Vector Components

Tags: vectors, geometry, gauss-law

[image]

How is $vcos(\theta)$ the perpendicular vector?

I think I'm missing something fundamental in my trig and vector knowledge...

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the E vectors coming out of the yellow surface into a component parallel to the surface and a component perpendicular to the surface:

$E = E_{parallel} + E_{perpendicular}$.

As I say to my students a lot of the time, draw the triangle! The triangle here has a hypotenuse of one of the E vectors (in red), one leg of the triangle is the normal, and the other is the projection of E along the surface. With theta marked correctly in the diagram, you should get that

$E_{parallel} = E \sin\theta$

and

$E_{perpendicular} = E \cos\theta$.